# Angular 2 Quickstart: wrong encoding of js files

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm very new to angular 2, so I'm trying to make this work: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

The problem which I have really confuses me. All JS files, which I get as a response, have strange encoding - basically, I see a bunch of hieroglyphs. Non-js files (html and css) are ok. Please see below, html is ok. Js - totally not.
[image]

[image]

Do you guys have any idea, what can it be? Computer culture is not Chinese or Japanese, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [notepad+](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)+ or any html editor with encode options available to change the page encoding:

1. Open your file with [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
2. Go to "**Encoding**" menu option in main menu
3. Select "**Convert to UTF-8-BOM**"
4. check if the page display correctly

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Strangely enough, some of the files had UTF-16. This solved it!

Answer (score 0):

This can be related to your js files encoding on your editor.